# Percentile if and

Tags: sas

I want to do a percentile if and to be able to calculate the percentile based on 2 conditions in proc sql in SAS

```
Proc sql;
Create table test
As select *
Pctl(75,value1); quit;
```

Comment: What does "percentile if" mean?  Please explain what calculation you are doing.  Show some example input and the desired output from that input.

Comment: Please consider marking previous questions as solved if they've been answered. You may also want to review the guidelines on how to ask a good question for better answers [ask].